# React Fiber ThreeJS Models animation now working, just snaps into place

Tags: reactjs, 3d

This is the model that I am using to load glb file I have

```
const Model = (props: any) => {
  const modelRef = useRef(null as any)
  const { scene } = useGLTF('/3d-models/' + props.path)
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  const { spring } = useSpring({
    spring: active,
    config: { mass: 5, tension: 200, friction: 20, precision: 0.0001, duration: 5000 },

  });
  const rotation = spring.to([0, 1], [0, Math.PI]);


  return <a.mesh rotation-y={rotation} onClick={() => setActive(!active)} ref={modelRef} >
    <primitive ref={modelRef} object={scene} {...props} />
  </a.mesh>
}
```

Even thought the rotation works and it goes where it should, it has absolutely no transition, it is just snapping into it and I have no idea how to fix that. Here's where I am calling this model component:

```
Canvas resize={{ scroll: false }} dpr={[1, 2]} frameloop={'demand'} camera={{ fov: 45 }} style={{ height: '20rem' }} gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }} >
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                  <Stage environment={"dawn"} >
                    <Model scale={1} zoom={10} path='cargo car.glb' />
                  </Stage>
                  <Preload all />
                </Suspense>
              </Canvas>
```